# asp ajax collapsepanelextender panel resize

Tags: asp.net, resize, panel

I have a asp.net web form where whose layout is given below. I tried to paste image in this thread, but since i am new user, I am not allowed to post images in the question.

THe layout is decription is below: The code creates one asp table with 1 row and 5 columns. Columns are referred to COl1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 in that order in the description below.

I have two collapse panel extenders which does following:
   1. Collapse Panel extender 1 controls asp panels in col1 and col2 respectively. Whenever col1 is pressed, col2 hides/shows
   2. Collapse Panel extender 2 controls asp panels in col4 and col5 respectively. Whenever col5 is pressed, col4 hides/shows

The below code works fine with Collapse panel initialization code in backend C# class.

Now my problem is, I want the asp panel in col3 to auto resize from its current size as per the behavior of Col2 and COl4 panels. Whenever this panels are hidden, Col3 should maximize to occupy the space of both Col2, Col3 and Col4. When Col2 and COl4 are shown, it should resize back to orizinal size.

I tried multiple approaches but none of it worked.

```
            <div id="page_content_middle">
                <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
                <asp:Table ID="page_content_middle_table" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" Width="1%">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeader1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgToggle1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/collapse.jpg" ImageAlign="Top" />
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" Width="14%">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo1" runat="server" Width="100%" height="100%" BorderStyle="Solid">
                                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#B5C7DE" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                                    Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
                                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                                    <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
                                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
                                    <Items>
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu1" Value="Menu1"></asp:MenuItem>
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu2" Value="Menu2"></asp:MenuItem>
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu3" Value="Menu3"></asp:MenuItem>
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu4" Value="Menu4"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    </Items>
                                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
                                </asp:Menu>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" Width="65%">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pageContent" runat="server">
                                Som random text
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" Width="19%">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInfo2" runat="server" Width="64px" BorderStyle="Solid">
                                Some Random Information
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" Width="1%">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlHeader2" runat="server" Width="15px" BorderStyle="Solid">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgToggle2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/collapse.jpg" ImageAlign="Top" />
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>

            </div>
```